# How to use a multiple criteria Alerts in tradingview

Tags: pine-script

is it possible to make multi alerts criteria for the deal to start ?
for example, when it's >50 RSI & MACD is Green (ONLY then the trade opens) and the two or more conditions to the sell order to be fulfiled.

i tried making two criteria's but it opens when it's meet any of the two alerts.
HOW to make the 2 or 3 alerts to work together ?

thanks a lot for your help beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use the `and` operator and combine your conditions together.

```
longCondition = (rsi > 50) and (macd_hist > 0) and (close > open)

if longCondition
    strategy.entry(“Long”, strategy.long)
```